# How to use one connection to the Internet for VPN and another for accessing other websites?

Tags: internet, vpn, proxy

I have two network cards. If I connect to a network using VPN then to access other websites I have to pass through a proxy server.

Is it possible to use my other network card to connect to the Internet directly without passing through the proxy?

Comment: I guess by connection to the internet you mean websites in particular. In that case you would need firewall that can route packets based on port/protocol or zones.

Its easy to do with linux unfortunately i cant help with windows but i think its worth to take a look at the windows firewall of windows 7 as it supports zone based configuration for each interface.

Maybe some windows expert will explain that :)

Answer (score 13):

What you are asking is called "Split DNS" or "Split Tunneling". The VPN appliance must support this OR you can manually enter the IP address and hostname information into your [hosts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) file.

From *[How to set up a split-tunnel VPN in Windows Vista](http://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/expert/KnowledgebaseAnswer/0,289625,sid14_gci1368533,00.html)*:

> You also asked about split tunneling,
>   so let's take a moment to explain that
>   concept before walking through the
>   process of creating a VPN connection.
>   By default, when you create a VPN
>   connection, Windows funnels all of the
>   communications from your computer
>   through the VPN. So, if you're logged
>   into a corporate VPN from home to
>   check your email, all of the other Web
>   surfing you're doing on your computer
>   is also being run through your
>   corporate network. This is the default
>   behavior because, from the company's
>   point of view, it's the safest way and
>   ensures all traffic is protected
>   regardless of the destination.
>
> You might not want this behavior,
>   however, for a couple of reasons.
>   First, it allows your company to
>   inspect all of your personal Web
>   traffic while connected to the VPN.
>   Second, it will likely slow down your
>   access to the Web, as everything must
>   first be sent through the VPN.
>
> Split tunneling, on the other hand,
>   configures the VPN connection so that
>   only traffic headed to computers on
>   the corporate network is sent through
>   the VPN connection. Other traffic
>   leaving your computer goes out through
>   your normal network connection.
>
> Follow these steps to set up a VPN
>   connection in Windows Vista that uses
>   split tunneling:
>
> 1. From the Control Panel, choose "Network & Internet."
> 2. Click "View Network Status and Tasks."
> 3. Click "Manage Network Connections."
> 4. Right-click on your VPN connection and select "Properties."
> 5. Select the "Networking" tab.
> 6. Highlight "Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IP v4)."
> 7. Click "Properties."
> 8. Click "Advanced."
> 9. Uncheck the "Use default gateway on remote network" box.
> 10. Click "OK" three times to close the windows you opened.
>
> From that point forward, only traffic
>   destined for your corporate network
>   will be sent through the VPN. All
>   other traffic will use the local
>   network.

**EDIT1**

The information that the Cisco VPN client is used wasn't in the original post, and it basically changes everything and much complicates any final solution.

The biggest problem is that the VPN server must have been configured to allow split tunneling. Otherwise, it just sandbags you in your computer.

Second, you can attempt to configure according to the Cisco article *[Configuring Cisco VPN Client 3.5 and the Cisco Integrated Client to Secure Nonencrypted Traffic While Using Split Tunneling](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/vpndevc/ps2284/products_configuration_example09186a0080094b02.shtml)*.

However, I can recommend from my experience one solution that solves the problem without any additional configuration. This solution is simply to install and call the Cisco VPN client from a virtual machine. Even if the Cisco client then attempts to sandbag you in, it will only sandbag the virtual machine, rather than your computer. Your own computer stays free and able to use the Internet, while the VPN is used from the virtual machine.

**EDIT2**

The Cisco VPN client creates a tunnel, which can be voluntary or compulsory. The type of the tunnel is dictated by the administrator of the VPN **server** to which you connect. The compulsory tunnel will cut off all access to any external computer, including the LAN, and is what I called the "sandbox".

For more information, see Compulsory Tunneling in the following articles.

- *[VPN Tunneling - Safe Passage for Data](http://www.vpntools.com/vpntools_articles/vpn-tunnel.htm)*
- *[Layer 2 Tunneling Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layer_2_Tunneling_Protocol)* (Wikipedia)

If you wish to become an expert in everything VPN, a good book is most recommended, since there is just too much information.

Comment: i am using cisco vpn client to connect. It was pre-configured. I can see the host name, user name for the connection. but the password is not visible. If I connect using the client I need to specify my own user name and password also.

Comment: there is no option "Use default gateway on remote network" in the Cisco VPN adapter that I am using. However there is a list in which the default gateway to the network has been specified with a metric of 1. Can I use this in some way?

Comment: @iamrohitbanga: See my edit.

Comment: yes that should work ... but for the sake of curiosity is it possible to implement Patkos's solution. I want to change the routing table entries systematically to achieve this. Another thing that I have in mind is that if I install a proxy server on my pc, then can I not direct all traffic from a particular browser through the server.

Comment: @iamrohitbanga: If there is no option "Use default gateway on remote network", then probably this site places you in the sandbox, so you can't have both connections on the same computer.

Comment: even with two network cards ... that is bad

Comment: @iamrohitbanga: The administrator of the VPN server thought this was a good idea. You can ask him to change this, but just remember that he might find this request quite suspicious.

Comment: i want to learn in detail about the different strategies that may be used to implement VPN, just out of curiosity. Can you point me to some good resources? Something with an academic touch of concepts will be helpful. simple google search does not give me good resources. all tutorials that i found cover the basic concepts.
Thanks

Comment: i also want to know, what is it in sandboxing that prevents me to use the other interface for by passing the VPN network to which I am connected via the first interface. all I want is that my computer should act as a router to select the interface for different applications. what interferes with this idea?

Comment: @iamrohitbanga: See my second edit.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, still applicable.
Been roaming the internet back and forth for an answer, didn't find anything that worked well.
So I applied some logic: what about using IP v4 on your NIC#1 and IP v6 on your NIC#2?

My corporate VPN (in my case) only routed all IP v4 traffic through its server.

I used a sample static IPv6 internal address for NIC #2 and was successfully able to create a point to point connection to another computer on my LAN. Will always work and stay the same pre/post VPN connection.

Food for thought.