# OpenVPN server redirect to domain name

Tags: routing, openvpn, domain, redirection

As an example, I want to redirect the IP address `123.123.123.123` to a domain like `example.com`. So when I connect to the IP `123.123.123.123` on the client, it connects to `example.com` instead but the client still thinks it's connecting to that IP.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use one connection to the Internet for VPN and another for accessing other websites?](https://superuser.com/questions/166555/how-to-use-one-connection-to-the-internet-for-vpn-and-another-for-accessing-othe)

Comment: No, it doesn't. I want to spoof the IP that I'm connected to without needing to have the domain name's IP address.

Comment: Use the `hosts` file.